# Developing in a docker container on an SSH server VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04, vscode-remote

I can connect to an Ubuntu remote server via SSH with VScode, and I would like to be able to select a python interpreter from within a running docker container on that UBUNTU server.

Is this possible?

I am connecting to the Ubuntu 16.04 server via Mac OS X.